# Is it possible to log every system/application pop-up window and see it later in Windows XP and later?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, logging

Few minutes ago while browsing internet with Firefox 8.0.1 for Windows XP (Professional 32bit) i saw that some pop up probably with system or Firefox information blinked (appeared and disappeared momentally) - it couldn't be ad popup because i was using facebook and Google.com when this happened. I didn't had time to read what was written, so i don't know what happened then.

And i like to know - is there in Windows XP and later Windows systems such option for power users that logs every system/3rd party applications info pop-ups? And if it is, how it works and how can i turn it on?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My research didn't yield an automatic way to do this, but I'm hoping to leave breadcrumbs for folks who need to solve this in various ways.

For your specific problem, the [Sysinternals process monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) might be able to help you catch it in flight, but it's probably more heavyweight than what you're looking for, as I suspect leaving it running all the time would be pretty resource-intensive.

Cobbling together something from existing parts might be tricky. [GetWindowText](https://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Microsoft/GetWindowText) lets you harvest the contents of a window, but it requires human intervention.  You might be able to write an [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm) script to run GetWindowText on all windows of a certain type, etc.

It's pretty clear that all of the pieces are there to make an application that would do this. Microsoft has a [Dialog Box Filter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/embedded/dialog-box-filter-a-new-feature-in-windows-embedded-standard-2011) included with Windows Embedded that monitors constantly for any dialog box with a specific title, and suppresses it.  I suspect that someone with more Windows development fu could probably crank something out relatively quickly that does exactly what you're describing.  Most of them probably haven't created one because Visual Studio and kin probably have tools built in to trace window creation. [WindowInterceptor](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24066/Intercept-and-Manage-Windows-Originated-by-Third-p) appears to be source code that would be a good starting point.

If I find something that's a better match, I'll update.  And when I get 10 rep, I'll come back and fix the URLs. :-)

Comment: Thanks for reply Royce :)
The thing is even i could write such app - but will have to invest a lot of my time. But the question is - why MS didn't implemented it into Windows XP or at least newer? Or maybe such tool is integrated into Windows, but hidden from others and available only for selected people - like Microsoft's MVP's? Who knows?